# MS VBA Access Insert Into value and function help request

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am new new to VBA.  I am trying to insert data from one form to a table.  I have run into a problem with the following code:

```
strSQL = "Insert into [KitInfo](KitID, KitType, ExpirationDate) values(Forms!CreateNewKit!KitID, 'HS2000', dmin([ExpirationDate]))"
```

I am trying to insert a minimum date from the current form to the "ExpirationDate" column table KitInfo.  Is there a way of calculating the minimum date and then inserting that into the "ExpirationDate" column?  I was thinking nesting a subquery but I couldn't figure out how to do it.  I have tried changing "values" to "select", but then this query doesn't run at all.

Comment: Is the Record Source of your form a query or a table?

Comment: The record source is a table.

Answer (score 2):

[DMin](https://support.office.com/client/DMin-DMax-Functions-f5c6de87-8752-4f29-ab4b-c554053d299f) requires you tell it where the data resides.  Use the name of a table or saved query for the function's second option, *domain*.  You can review the *Application.DMin Method* topic in Access' help system for further details.

Create a query in the Access query designer to work out the syntax.

```sql
INSERT INTO [KitInfo]
(KitID, KitType, ExpirationDate)
VALUES
(Forms!CreateNewKit!KitID, 'HS2000', DMin('[ExpirationDate]', 'YourTable'))
```

Replace *YourTable* with the name of your table.

After you have the `INSERT` working correctly in the query designer, update your VBA code to create the same statement.